# FastAPI app running on two different ports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, port, fastapi

I have a project spread out across three repos, two of which contain an API: a main API and a helper API, which is called by the main API. Both APIs are implemented in FastAPI (`fastapi==0.89.0`); I'm using Python 3.9.12 in VSCode. The structure of both repositories is similar to each other:

```
# repo structure for both API repos:
|__ app
     |__ main.py
     |__ routers.py
     |__ #some subfolders
```

Each repo has its own virtual environment. The source code in the non-API repo is installed in the virtual environments of both API repos, in editable mode (`pip install -e`). The main API is running on port 8000; the helper API on port 8005:

```
# repo 1, main.py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from gunicorn.http import message

from app.routers import router

app = FastAPI(description="main API")

app.include_router(router)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

Script for helper API:

```
# repo 2, main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI

import uvicorn
from gunicorn.http import message
from app.routers import router

# fastapi app
app = FastAPI(
    title="helper API")

app.include_router(router)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8005)
```

The `routers.py` scripts in the two repos is identical, except for the tags passed to `include_router`:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

from app.pipeline import view

router = APIRouter()

router.include_router(view.router, tags=["different tag here"])
```

When I run the two main.py scripts in separate terminals, the info that gets printed to these terminals is as expected:

```
# terminal for helper API
INFO:     Started server process [4650]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8005 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

```
# terminal for main API
INFO:     Started server process [4681]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However, when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs`, then the endpoints of the helper API, and not the main API, are exposed there. So the helper API somehow seems to 'override' the main API on port 8000, and its endpoints are accessible at 2 ports: 8000 and 8005. The endpoints of the main API, by contrast, are not accessible anywhere. At first I thought it might be due to my VSCode settings, but some googling proved fruitless. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is this in one, common codebase? You're importing the same router in both cases, so in that case it'll be exactly the same content in both APIs. Since you haven't included your actual router code or project layout, it's hard to say anything else.,

Comment: @MatsLindh Good point, I edited the post to clarify! The two APIs are stored in separate repos, and each of them have a router (so it's not one and the same router).

Comment: Do you see requests logged in both consoles, or just one of them? Are you using the same virtual environment for both, and both are modules named `app`? (so you end up overwriting the previous module reference if you did `pip install -e .` or similar with a different packaging system); in general, I'm guessing you're actually importing the same code since they're named the same and in the same enviornment or venv, so the last overrides the first one).

Comment: @MatsLindh Requests are being logged in both consoles; each repo has its own `app` folder, and each repo has its own virtual environment... I can access `/docs` for both APIs, but they both display the same endpoints.

Comment: Which seems to indicate that they're importing the same `app.router` - if you run Python with `-v` it'll show which files are being read and included for each import statement.

Comment: I ran `python3 -v app/main.py` for both repos, and the memory location of `app.router` is different in each case: `import 'app.routers' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x107320dc0>` (for main API); `import 'app.routers' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x103f4d310>` (for helper API). This thing is driving me crazy :D

Comment: @Chris If I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs from an incognito window or a different browser, I get the exact same thing: the endpoints that should only be running on the 8005 port.

Comment: @Chris I've tried both `uvicorn main:app` and `python3 -m app/main.py` - same result.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for your comments, they helped me a lot to fix the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause: at some point I must have prepended the helper API repo to my PYTHONPATH, the result being that when I ran the two main.py scripts, one and the same router got imported. Removing the helper API repo from the PYTHONPATH variable fixed the problem.